# What is the difference between graphics filters in Adventure Game Studio?

Tags: adventure-game-studio

[Adventure Game Studio](http://www.adventuregamestudio.co.uk/) supports following graphics filters:

- max nearest-neighbour filter and 2x-8x nearest-neighbour filter
- 2x-8x anti-aliasing filter

What graphics filter offers the best image quality? What is the difference between "nearest-neighbour filter" and "anti-aliasing filter"?

[image: Adventure Game Studio configuration]

Answer (score 3):

The filter that gives the "best" results will depend on the particular aesthetic you are going for.

The graphics filters have two components. The "x" portion of the filter refers to how many times the filter scales the source pixels. A "2x" filter doubles them, a "3x" filter triples them, et cetera. Think of them like magnification or zoom levels.

The next component to the filter is how the resulting scaled pixels are interpolated. A "nearest-neighbor" interpolation filter is essentially a no-op for integer zoom levels like those provided by AGS. This will result in a *blocky* image.

An anti-aliasing filter, by contrast, tries to smooth jagged edges (aliasing) in the scaled pixels. There are several different ways of implementing anti-aliasing and it's not clear which methods AGS uses. However, the result will generally be smoother than a nearest-neighbor interpolation filter, which is generally a more desirable, "modern" look... although there will be a tendency for actual, desirable hard edges in images to get fuzzy.

The scaling factor affects how big the resulting images are on screen, the nearest-neighbor versus anti-aliasing factor affects how smooth the resulting pixels look. You'll have to experiment with both and pick the one you think looks best for your game's art style.

Comment: I find it odd that AGS configuration tool shows the game running in `6400 x 4800` resolution, although AGS only supports `800 x 600`: http://i.imgur.com/3jFvD8Q.png

Comment: @user598527 You have an 8x filter selected; 800x600 scaled up by a factor of eight is 6400x4800, so it seems likely that it is applying the scale factor to the base resolution to arrive at that number.